# Sign in redirects to home page instead of staying on same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I installed devise and it is working properly but the sign in redirect. When user signs in from any page of app, Devise redirects user to home instead of redirecting on same page. I tried implementing How_to solutions of devise but no help.

I wrote in application_controller:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 current_user_path 
end
```

But it gives error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user_path' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0xaeacc34>
```

When i write:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 current_user_path 
end
```

It gives :

```
undefined method `user_url'
```

Whats the solution for this problem? Can any body help in this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use request.referer

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  request.referer
end
```

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know why this didn't get more upvotes.  Of all the other solutions proposed, this was the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect to somewhere else in which scenerio(error or success)? Usually after_sign_in_path_for used after user logged in successfully. SO:

if you haven't override devise default functionality then use below code for navigate control to specific custom page. `current_user` is also accessible in this action.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource)
    scope_path = :"#{scope}_root_path"
    respond_to?(scope_path, true) ? send(scope_path) : root_url
end
```

Update:
Another example is as follows:

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    current_user.admin? ? dashboard_admin_home_index_path : current_user.sign_in_count >= 1 ? "/home/dashboard" : "/#{current_user.role}/dashboard"
  end
```

Comment: in the above code of scope as well, it is redirecting to home page. I need user to stay on the same page where he was before.